# Вывод в форме информации об объекте по его ID

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

В БД есть две таблицы: `"ребенок"` и `"родитель"`. В таблице `"ребенок"` есть поле `"ид_родителя"`.

В форме создания и редактирования `"ребенка"` в своем Yii-проекте делаю такое поле в форме:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'parent')->dropDownList(
    ArrayHelper::map(Parents::find()->all(), 'id', 'f_name'), ['prompt' => 'Выберите родителей']
) ?>
```

И когда я сохраняю запись, то вижу в поле `Родитель` ID родителя.

Как сделать так, чтобы в поле БД сохранялся ID, но при выводе показывалось имя, которое есть в БД?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В модель "ребёнка"

```
public function getParent()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Parent::className(), ['что "связывать"' => 'с чем "связывать"']);
    }

public function getParentName()
{
    return $this->parent->Название;
}
```

В качестве примера:

```
public function getUser()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(\common\models\User::className(), ['id' => 'user_id']);
    }

    public function getUserName()
    {
        return $this->user->username;
    }
```

При выводе просто заместо

```
$model->id_родителя
```

поставьте

```
$model->parentName
```

Comment: Подскажите, а вот в методе getParentName() я беру $this->parent->parentname, но мне пишет: Trying to get property of non-object     в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Кратко говоря не найден объект, убедитесь что существую нужные записи в бд, а также проверьте ещё раз ['что "связывать"' => 'с чем "связывать"'], если не ошибаюсь в вашем случае примерно должно быть так ['id' => 'child_id']

Comment: Большое спасибо за помощь!  Вы все верно расписали (только сейчас смог проверить)